# Access YAML variable in inline PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

If I have a YAML Pipeline;

```
variables:
- name  : myVariable
  value : 'abcd'
```

and if I want to run some inline powershell - how can i access that value (abcd) in the powershell script;

I expected this to work - but it didnt;

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Do the thing"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 
        write-host $(myVariable)
```

Comment: Afaik, there is no native YAML parsers in PowerShell, but there are a few external ones, like: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/powershell-yaml

Comment: Hi @James Cooke, According to you description, I have tested it and it works, I have shared the yaml definition and result below, you could check it. If I misunderstood you, please describe your question in more detail. The complete Yaml definition is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#variables) to specify variables at the pipeline, stage, or job level.

YAML build definition:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

variables:
- name  : myVariable
  value : 'abcd'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Do the thing"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 
      write-host $(myVariable)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this works in Azure DevOps, but in GitLab it's:

```
$VAR_NAME
```

or

```
$env:VAR_NAME
```

I'm using these two line in existing yaml and they work fine:

```
- $PKG_VERSION = (Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.version).basename
- Write-Host $PKG_VERSION
```

Comment: If you don't know if your answer is correct, don't post it as an answer.